# OpenCV and Android Studio and Ndk Panorama Application

Tags: android, c++, opencv, gradle, android-ndk

i'am using Android Studio Trying to Achieve a panorama application
i started with an OpenCV sample called pandorica
link : https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-opencv-panorama/

i set up every thing and built the project
but my fonction Stitch is not found
i think that ndk is not working
even if it has compiled .so (shared libs) files

```
      JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_administrateur_cameraapp_MainActivity_Stitch(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray args)
```

this is my build.gradle

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set .so files location to libs
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}

// call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine 'C:\\\\Android\\\\android-ndk-r11b\\\\ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    } else {
        commandLine 'C:\\\\Android\\\\android-ndk-r11b\\\\ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

this is the error

Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function Java_com_example_administrateur_cameraapp_MainActivity_Stitch

i am using
Android version 1.5.1
OpenCV 2.3.1
Gradle 2.8
Ndk r11b

My Goal is to achieve a panorama android application and I choose OpenCV 2.3.1 because opensource project used it

If there is a tutorial of OpenCV 3.0 panorama application, Please Post the link here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem 
You need to create a JNI folder inside your project and pass the needed libraries there... 
I had the same problem along with Imgproc.circle\line
And solved it by doing that[image]

Comment: jni folder inside project but where exactly ?

Comment: I have added  a picture for you hope it helps